# Retrieving the "recommended" playlist via API call?

Tags: soundcloud

for any given song, e.g.

https://soundcloud.com/shesthequeen/i-dont-wanna-know

SoundCloud has a "recommended" playlist that usually start playing after that song is finished:

https://soundcloud.com/shesthequeen/i-dont-wanna-know/recommended

How can I retrieve this "recommended" playlist via the SoundCloud API? Is there a way? Which connector should I use? I'd like to avoid scraping HTML.

Thanks in advance,
Mary

Comment: This is internal SoundCloud feature and unfortunately is not availabe through public API, sorry :(

Answer (score 7):

Looks like that this will be a new subresource of the upcoming tracks endpoint in the next API version.

```
GET /tracks/{id}/related
```

These are the API calls:

https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/tracks/102113299/related?anon_user_id=36331428&limit=10&offset=0&linked_partitioning=1

https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/tracks/102113299/related

Comment: Letting you know, that using undocumented APIs is not going in line with the our developers’ [Terms of Use](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/terms-of-use). I'd also not recommend building anything on top of it, as it is very much subject to change.

Comment: @gryzzly very true, but being an explorer mostly led to discovery of new lands and joy :)