# Can the "Play more tracks like" feature be disabled in the Soundcloud API?

Tags: soundcloud

Is it possible to remove the "Play more tracks like" feature from the embedded player?

I'm trying to use the embedded player as is on my website but this feature is affecting how the player appears. I've created images that represent my songs and the "Play more tracks like" feature obscures a 3rd of the image and looks awful.

If a song is paused/ended, I'd like just the original image to remain with the waveform filled in.

I've looked at the settings in the API playground and none of them disable this feature. Can it be done?

Example of image being covered by the feature:

Without:

[image: without]

With:

[image: with]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the response I got from Soundcloud about this issue:

"Thanks for getting in touch about this, and my apologies for any confusion. With a Free account, recommended tracks by other users will display when your song finishes playing on the embedded widget. To change this display, you need a Pro Unlimited account, and then you can choose which tracks display when your track stops playing."

It is odd because with the free account you have access to the code and there's that "hide_related=true" part...it just doesn't work. Maybe you have to pay to get that to happen? In any case it's annoying that it isn't listed transparently in the features of the paid plan anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for posting. I have a Pro account and would think seriously about an upgrade to Pro Unlimited for this feature if it definitely exists. I'll try the 30 day trial and see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that the feature hide_related does not work at the moment - maybe a bug?
But anyway, this will be a new feature of the upcoming API, gryzzly from SoundCloud told us here: [Retrieving the "recommended" playlist via API call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388089/retrieving-the-recommended-playlist-via-api-call)

But if you change the embed code to visual=false, you wont see the recommendations if you stop playing - only at the end of the track. But the player does not look that sexy anymore.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="250" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/165731256&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=true&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=false"></iframe>

<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/165731256&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=true&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/8bvkvhm6/

Comment: Thanks. It would have been useful but I can work around it with some CSS. I'm not sure @gryzzly is saying what you seem to think he is though..?