# soundcloud: Is api-v2 allowed to be used and is there documentation on it?

Tags: soundcloud

yea, the title pretty much sums it up. Is it allowed for an app to access ressources on api-v2.soundcloud.com?
Is there any documentation for it?

Relevant since I'm currently working on a soundcloud app and I just recognized that most of the calls on the websites itself are done with api-v2. The responses from the server would be extremly helpful to build some kind of infinite streaming which is the feature I like most about soundcloud.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant speak for SoundCloud, but [gryzzly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236135/gryzzly) (a former SoundCloud engineer) stated in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388089/retrieving-the-recommended-playlist-via-api-call/26390142#26390142):

> Letting you know, that using undocumented APIs is not going in line with the our developers’ Terms of Use.