# How to fetch playback statistics

Tags: soundcloud

I'd like to know if it's possible (and if yes: how) to fetch statistics for our soundcloud tracks via the soundcloud API.

I know that i can get the current playback count of my tracks but is it possible to get the playback count of yesterday and so on to draw a custom graph ?

Or do i have to poll the api and record the data myself?

Answer (score 4):

Not officially. Latest and official api does not support this feature yet. It voilates the tos.

Check that question first, before you read further:
[soundcloud: Is api-v2 allowed to be used and is there documentation on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253633/soundcloud-is-api-v2-allowed-to-be-used-and-is-there-documentation-on-it/29258809#29258809)

For experimental use, you can try this:

soundcloud.com/{username}/stats

Is a good starting point to take a deeper look on the networks tab in the console.

Example calls:

totals -> all tracks

https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:1672444/stats/totals?from=1427846400000&to=1428364800000&client_id=b45b1aa10f1ac2941910a7f0d10f8e28&app_version=1d6991e

plays -> individual tracks

https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:1672444/tracks/soundcloud:tracks:148976759/stats/timeseries/plays?from=1427846400000&to=1428364800000&resolution=day&client_id=b45b1aa10f1ac2941910a7f0d10f8e28&app_version=1d6991e

The second call will give you, what you want - an array with the daily plays.

To make the calls working i had to manipulate the request headers.

- Origin https://soundcloud.com
- Referer https://soundcloud.com
- Host api-v2.soundcloud.com
- Authorization (copied from network tab)

[image: example postman call]

Comment: What tool are you using to call the URLs?