# Soundcloud API: Find track like date via API

Tags: soundcloud

I've tried searching through Stack Overflow as well as the Soundcloud API reference but couldn't find any answer. I'm trying to retrieve the date a user liked a song on Soundcloud. I tried two parts of the API:

**- /users/{id}/favorites:** This will return all tracks liked by the user, but no date when it was liked.

**- /me/activities:** This returns track reposts, comments and seemingly tracks that show up on the stream. Sadly there doesn't seem to be a type track-like, but maybe I'm doing something wrong here or need to pass additional parameters.

I'm having the user log into Soundcloud before utilizing the API.

Any chance someone knows if retrieving the track like date via the API is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the public API available right now, this is not possible.

You have to build it on your own and track the changes in a different, your own database.

Example call from the website when you lookup your likes, i dont know what you will see with a pro account:

https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:1672444/stats/timeseries/likes?from=1442016000000&to=1442534400000&resolution=day&tracks=soundcloud%3Atracks%3A30984358&client_id=02gUJC0hH2ct1EGOcYXQIzRFU91c72Ea&app_version=39e9f65

Response:

[{"user_urn":"soundcloud:users:1672444","timeseries":[{"time":1442016000000,"count":1},{"time":1442534400000,"count":1}]},{"user_urn":"soundcloud:users:1672444","track_urn":"soundcloud:tracks:30984358","timeseries":[{"time":1442016000000,"count":1},{"time":1442534400000,"count":1}]}]

Here is and older, related answer about playback stats: 
[How to fetch playback statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489845/how-to-fetch-playback-statistics)

Comment: Thanks that's perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

This is some python code that will hit an undocumented `track_likes` endpoint that will reveal the like date:

```
import requests
import json
import pdb
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime

def get_next_page(url):
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'OAuth YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_HERE',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7)...',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Origin': 'https://soundcloud.com',
        'Referer': 'https://soundcloud.com/',
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    return data.get('next_href'), data.get('collection', [])

def construct_buckets():
    url = "https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/YOUR_USER_ID/track_likes?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&limit=1000&offset=0&linked_partitioning=1&app_version=1689322736&app_locale=en"
    _, collection = get_next_page(url)

    buckets = defaultdict(list)
    cutoff_date = datetime.strptime('April 2021', '%B %Y')

    for item in collection:
        track = item['track']
        liked_at = datetime.strptime(item['created_at'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

        if liked_at < cutoff_date:
            continue

        liked_at_bucket = liked_at.strftime("%B %Y")

        buckets[liked_at_bucket].insert(0, track)
        print(f"Added track '{track['title']}' to bucket '{liked_at_bucket}'")

    return buckets

buckets = construct_buckets()
```