# Soundcloud API user reposts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, soundcloud

Is it possible get user reposts in soundcloud API?

I found a solution:

```
https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/profile/soundcloud:users:{user.id}?client_id=key
```

...but it's an undocumented feature

Comment: And your question is?

In case you are wondering if you are allowed to use it, see for example the comment of one of the soundcloud developers here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388089/retrieving-the-recommended-playlist-via-api-call/26390142#26390142
(via 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253633/soundcloud-is-api-v2-allowed-to-be-used-and-is-there-documentation-on-it)

Answer (score 0):

Currently the SoundCloud API does not support anything relating to reposting tracks. I have attempted to use this exact endpoint using a GET request, but as of the time of writing this the CORS settings on their server don't allow external connections. I also attempted a JSONP request, which is a way around the CORS issue, but it doesn't like the colons in the request URL.