# Is SoundCloud api-v2 being deprecated?

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome-extension, soundcloud

We have been using the SoundCloud API and it suddenly stopped working earlier this week; it now return a "Not Found" message. Nothing changed on our side as far we know, so we are wondering if there are some known changes to the API that would require code change?

Here's an example of the URL we are using to access the API:
https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/explore/Popular+Music?client_id=d2791ef3c22de81af61b4915a654b2e2&cb=1462986650375-9904013473612631

This is used within Javascript code for a new tab extension for Chrome on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs do not mention `api-v2` endpoints.

> Unless otherwise specified, the base URL for API endpoints is:
>
> ```
> https://api.soundcloud.com
> ```

Try changing the base URL; if you're using the JS SDK, make sure you have the latest version of it.

---

Looks like `api-v2` is an [undocumented, internal version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253633/soundcloud-is-api-v2-allowed-to-be-used-and-is-there-documentation-on-it) of SoundCloud API.

There is even a [quote from the developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388089/retrieving-the-recommended-playlist-via-api-call/26390142#comment41450304_26390142) (emphasis mine):

> Letting you know, that using undocumented APIs is not going in line with the our developers’ Terms of Use. **I'd also not recommend building anything on top of it, as it is very much subject to change.**

So there you go. It's possible that this endpoint changes, there's no documentation publicly available, you're not supposed to use it anyway and you're breaking ToS if you do, even though [SoundCloud doesn't seem to be feeling bloodthirsty](https://twitter.com/SoundCloudDev/status/639017606264016896). What's important is to understand there's no official support for it (aka "will break everything you did at any moment").

Answer (score 0):

The v1 API is the one being deprecated in my opinion. the official python repository for the SoundCloud v1 API itself clarifies that. Soundcloud, as of now (since almost 2 years in fact, at the time of writing) is not accepting app registrations since they're in the middle of improving their developer platform, but it's been almost 2 years (it started in late 2019) and app registrations for the API are still not up, neither is there any documentation for the v2 API.

the only possibly way to make use of the SoundCloud API is to consider the fact that that the SoundCloud website itself makes use of the v2 API as of right now

Just taking a look at the network tab of the browser devtools while logged in exposes one's SoundCloud client and user ids, from there's on, just keep on looking at the different endpoints the website hits while being used, and there you have most of the functionality you'll need from the v2 API.

still, it's just a workaround and is subject to change any time and SC cannot be held liable for breaking of any apps we build on top of the API