# SoundCloud API 403 Search Endpoint

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I am wanting to make use of the SoundCloud API so a user can search for an artist and then click their tracks to get an embed code.

I am using the SDK and the embed function works fine as follows:

```
   SC.initialize({
        client_id: 'XXXXXXX'
    }); 

    var track_url = 'https://soundcloud.com/forss/flickermood';
    SC.oEmbed(track_url, { auto_play: true }).then(function(oEmbed) {
    console.log('oEmbed response: ', oEmbed);
    });
```

But when I use the search endpoint I get 403.

```
  SC.get('/tracks', {
      q: 'buskers', license: 'cc-by-sa'
    }).then(function(tracks) {
        console.log(tracks);
    });
```

I noticed that SoundCloud uses a v2 api for the search on their site - is this documented anywhere?

I haven't been able to register an app and I have seen it's been closed for a while - I'm wondering what I need to do to get past this 403 and if it's because my client_id which I grabbed from my browser.

Any insight would be great - the API looks fairly extensive but void if I can't use it.

Comment: HTTP 403 error means access is forbidden. You need to get access token to get access to endpoint

Comment: Heres a [docs](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#playing) for soundcloud.

Comment: @JohnMcLane I'm passing my client_id - there isn't anywhere in the docs saying about an access token it just says client_id or access token. 403 is "You don't have access to whatever it is you're asking for." so surely its locked down?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Did you find a solution @AidanDaniel ?

Comment: @Benbb96 I didn't get anywhere with it sorry - it seems like they shut it down as I couldn't even get a dev account to set up a new app which is strange because their forum and Twitter seem active! We've put it on the back burner as we didn't need the integration immediately.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your answer. It may not be official but I find a way to get some endpoints working by using the api-v2 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221510/is-soundcloud-api-v2-being-deprecated