# 401 Unauthorized when connecting to api-v2.soundcloud.com

Tags: soundcloud

I started to get the following error recent when making a simple GET call to the Soundcloud API.

```
* About to connect() to api-v2.soundcloud.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 99.84.179.62...
* Connected to api-v2.soundcloud.com (99.84.179.62) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=*.soundcloud.com,OU=Domain Control Validated
*   start date: Apr 12 11:01:17 2018 GMT
*   expire date: Jun 08 10:08:48 2020 GMT
*   common name: *.soundcloud.com
*   issuer: CN=GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - SHA256 - G2,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,C=BE
> GET /charts?kind=trending&genre=soundcloud%3Agenres%3Adubstep&client_id=<REDACTED>&limit=20&offset=0 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: api-v2.soundcloud.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Sat, 13 Apr 2019 20:26:31 GMT
< Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
< Server: am/2
< Vary: Origin
< X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
< Via: 1.1 237bd7e86f7f99cead16dc4ecb5fed20.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< X-Amz-Cf-Id: EnRw9o_d0W_hSzrH6Vi9TqAfQKuNGzlZJFTz54B3noU_Ryg_l6sIGA==
<
* Connection #0 to host api-v2.soundcloud.com left intact
```

I have not changed my credentials in any way, so I do not understand why this error is happening all of the sudden.

Comment: Did you find a way to resolve it?

Comment: Elaborating on my answer: Are you doing something that's only available in api-v2, and not the public API?  If so, can you add that to your question?

Answer (score 0):

`api-v2.soundcloud.com` is an undocumented API used by SoundCloud internally and should not be used by any developer client applications.  [Using it breaks the SoundCloud ToS and changes to it could be made at any time.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388089/retrieving-the-recommended-playlist-via-api-call/26390142#comment41450304_26390142)  Please use `api.soundcloud.com` for all API requests.

Comment: I tried also using api.soundcloud.com but the error remains the same.